# Repeat animation infinitely

Tags: gsap

Why do the green and yellow blocks loop here:

http://jsfiddle.net/NK3pe/23/

and yet not here:

http://jsfiddle.net/NK3pe/27/

```
var trackMaster = new TimelineLite({ paused: false, repeat: -1 });

function addParticle(particleClass){
    $('#display').append("<div class='" + particleClass + "' style='color: black'></div>"); 
}

for(i = 0; i < 300; i++){
   var particle = addParticle('slow');

   trackMaster.insertMultiple( TweenLite.from( $('.slow')[i], Math.random() * 20, { left:'+=200', ease: Linear.easeNone, repeat: -1 }), 0 );

}

function midAnimation(){
     trackMaster.time(8);   
}

$('#restart').on('click', function(){
    trackMaster.restart();
});

$('#pause').on('click', function(){
    trackMaster.pause();
});

$('#resume').on('click', function(){
    trackMaster.resume();
});
```

I'm applying the `repeat: -1` option. It doesn't repeat if I do `repeat: 2` either...

Comment: Note that, in the first line, `repeat: -1` is ignored. More specifically, once the proper solution is implemented as per @Igor's answer, the value for `repeat` in this first line does not affect the animations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change:** `trackMaster.insertMultiple( TweenLite.from( $('.slow')[i], Math.random() * 20, { left:'+=200', ease: Linear.easeNone, repeat: -1 }), 0 );`

**to:** `trackMaster.from( $('.slow')[i], Math.random() * 20, { left:'+=200', ease: Linear.easeNone, repeat: 33 }, 0 );`

Comment: The question title specifically asks about looping infinitely. Thus the solution should really include `repeat: -1` instead of `repeat: 33`. (I acknowledge that the actual 2nd jsfiddle, tho' not the code posted in the question, uses `repeat: 33`, so this answer was perhaps just trying to make the smallest number of changes to get the looping to work, but just thought I'd make the answer actually address the question title.)